# Block file browsing on Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, citrix

I have a Citrix application that open Windows Explorer from a menu. The command invoked to open Explorer is: Explorer "g:\app\folder"

What happens when Explorer is opened is that it shows a window with the contents of g:\app\folder on the server which is hosting the Citrix application, this is ok, however, I can see the other folders of the server,I can even browse to the C:\ drive of the server that host the application, and I want to avoid that, I just want to be able to see G:\app\folder and that's all, I don't want to allow the user to see any other file than the ones that are on that folder.

Anybody know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable and hide the C: with Group Policy but be warned that it's not 100% fool proof. Ensure your write permissions are good and that you're users aren't administrators, but if you're letting someone connect to a machine you shouldn't have anything directly sensitive on that machine.

Citrix best practice would be to Silo sensitive apps and data into their own group of servers, limiting access as required.

Comment: Right. There are 2 GP settings that can accomplish the C: drive access part of the problem (but not foolproof as you stated). If the G: drive is a mapped drive then I might suggest enabling ABE on the parent/root share.

Comment: Thanks, I found a GP to hide drives, so users will not be able to see them, however, they can still see Desktop and other shortcuts that I don't want the users to see. Best option would be to hide the whole navigation pane, but I don't find a GP that do this, do you know that GP by any chance?